# Making a function to take the inverse fourier transform

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, fft

I am trying to take the inverse fourier transform by making my own function. This is the function to take the Fourier transform of my time series which appears to work fine.

```
def DFT(x, frequencies):
    N1 = x.size
    k = frequencies.size
    t = np.arange(N1)
    fourier = np.zeros(k)
    for i in range(0,k):
        fourier[i] = np.dot(x,(1/k)*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*frequencies[i]*t))
    return fourier
```

This is my original signal (just a sine wave):

```
N2 = 1*10**6
time = np.arange(0,N2,1000)
lam = .1*10**6
f = 1/lam
freq = np.arange(0,.05,.0001)


signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*time)
```

And the power spectrum is plotted using my DFT (fourier function):

```
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(DFT(signal,freq))**2)
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Spectrum of Sine Wave')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

but when I try to apply my function for the inverse fourier transform, I am not getting my original sine wave back:

```
def IFT(fft, frequencies):
    N = fft.size
    k = frequencies.size
    n = np.arange(N)
    inverse_fourier = np.zeros(k)
    for i in range(0,k):
        inverse_fourier[i] = np.dot(fft,np.exp((-2j*np.pi*frequencies[i]*n)/N)) #[None,:]
    return inverse_fourier
```

What is wrong with my function? I get no errors, but the returned signal is totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inverse the exponent should be positive (`2j` instead of `-2j`) and drop the `/N`, which gives (added plots for demonstration):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def DFT(x, frequencies):
    N1 = x.size
    k = frequencies.size
    t = np.arange(N1)
    fourier = np.zeros(k)
    for i in range(0,k):
        fourier[i] = np.dot(x, (1/k)*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*frequencies[i]*t))
    return fourier

def IFT(fft, frequencies):
    N = fft.size
    k = frequencies.size
    n = np.arange(N)
    inverse_fourier = np.zeros(k)
    for i in range(0,k):
        inverse_fourier[i] = np.dot(fft, np.exp((2j*np.pi*frequencies[i]*n))) #[None,:]
    return inverse_fourier

N2 = 1*10**6
time = np.arange(0,N2,2000)
lam = .1*10**6
f = 1/lam
freq = np.arange(0,.05,.0001)

signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*time)

plt.plot(time, signal)
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.title('Sine Wave')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

dft = DFT(signal, freq)

plt.plot(freq, np.abs(dft)**2)
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Spectrum of Sine Wave')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

plt.plot(time, IFT(dft, freq))
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.title('Sine Wave')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

which gives (first sin graph omitted):

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Running you code you should get the following warning:

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  fourier[i] = np.dot(x,(1/k)*np.exp(-2j*np.pi*frequencies[i]*t))
```

Since the resulting Fourier transform should be complex valued, this warning should be reasons for concerns. To get rid of this warning you may initialize `fourier` like so:

```
fourier = np.zeros(k, dtype=complex)
```

Also the formula for [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) includes summations over frequencies covering the complete `[0,1)` range. To get a 1000-point DFT (as you had in your code) you'd then have to use

```
freq = np.arange(0,1,.001)
```

This will result in a spectrum that includes 2 spikes: one at the expected frequency, and another symmetric one above the Nyquist frequency. It is common to discard the results above the Nyquist frequency when plotting the spectrum of real-valued signals (but use the full spectrum into your `IFT` function).

Finally, as [GrimTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8166596/grimtrigger) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370686/2994596):

> your inverse the exponent should be positive (2j instead of -2j) and drop the /N